# Having trouble correctly producing time series plot

Tags: r, datetime, plot, time-series

I am trying to plot a time series from an excel file in R Studio. It has a single column named 'Dates'. This column contains datetime data of customer visits in the form 2/15/2014 6:17:22 AM. The datetime was originally in char format and I converted it into a Large POSIXct value using lubridate:

```r
tsData <- mdy_hms(fullUsage$Dates)
```

Which gives me a value:

```
POSIXct[1:25,354], format: "2018-04-13 10:18:14" "2018-04-14 13:27:11" .....
```

I then tried converting it into a time series object using the code below:
require(xts)

```
visitTimes.ts <- xts(tsData, start = 1, order.by=as.POSIXct(tsData))

plot(visitTimes.ts)

ts_plot(visitTimes.ts)

ts_info(visitTimes.ts)
```

Im not 100% sure but it looks like the plot is coming out using the sum count of visits. I believe my problem may be in correctly indexing my data using the dates. I apologize in advance if this is a simple issue to deal with I am still learning R. I have included the screenshot of my plot.

[image: timeseries plot]

Comment: Hi Munir. What is it you want to plot on the y axis? Is it visits per week, per day, per hour, per minute?

Comment: Hi Allan, I would like to display the visits hourly and monthly. I initially was just trying to plot it any way I could and then tweak my code from there.

Answer (score 0):

yes you are right, you need to provide both the date column (x axis) and the value (y axis)

here's a simple example:

```
v1 <- data.frame(Date = mdy_hms(c("1-1-2020-00-00-00", "1-2-2020-00-00-00", "1-3-2020-00-00-00")), Value = c(1, 3, 6))
v2 <- xts(v1["Value"], order.by = v1[, "Date"])
plot(v2)
```

first argument of xts takes the x values, on the order.by i leave the actual ts object

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the number of events in each time period and plot these values on the y axis. You didn't provide enough data for a reproducible example, so I have created a small example. We'll use the tidyverse packages `dplyr` and `lubridate` to help us out here:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(69)
fullUsage <- data.frame(Dates = as.POSIXct("2020-01-01") +
                                minutes(round(cumsum(rexp(10000, 1/25))))
                       )
head(fullUsage)
#>                 Dates
#> 1 2020-01-01 00:02:00
#> 2 2020-01-01 00:15:00
#> 3 2020-01-01 00:22:00
#> 4 2020-01-01 00:29:00
#> 5 2020-01-01 01:13:00
#> 6 2020-01-01 01:27:00
```

First of all, we will create columns that show the hour of day and the month that events occurred:

```
fullUsage$hours  <- hour(fullUsage$Dates)
fullUsage$month  <- floor_date(fullUsage$Dates, "month")
```

Now we can effectively just count the number of events per month and plot this number for each month:

```
fullUsage %>% 
  group_by(month) %>% 
  summarise(n = length(hours)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(month, n)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]

And we can do the same for the hour of day:

```r
fullUsage %>% 
  group_by(hours) %>% 
  summarise(n = length(hours)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(hours, n)) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 0:23) +
  labs(y = "Hour of day")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>